# Suggestion of using Activity or Fragment or Dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, fragment

I have an `Activity`, in which I've used `WebView`.
I am loading given server URL in it. Its all working fine. There are several pages in it which I can navigate through.
In one of the page of Website (server URL), for example 'Product Description', there is a button named "Try This", which is basically to try the product that user can have a try.
When user touches this button, using JavaScriptInterface, I am calling one JavaScript function and getting the image URL and loading this in another `Activity`.
But when I presses the back button from this child Activity, its gets redirected to the very first page of the `WebView` i.e list of products, but not the last page that I visited.
How can I fix the back button navigation for this?

Second scenario, I've used is using custom dialog, in which I am able to load the picture successfully. What I want is the ability to have user interaction in this custom dialog. For Example, is it possible that user can drag, move, zoom, resize and capture picture from camera all in this custom dialog box? How can I achieve this, if it's feasible?

Third case, which I don't know exactly is to use Fragments.

Please suggest me how can I overcome this situation.
It would be best if I can use `Activty` without having back button navigation issue from the child activity.

Answer (score 0):

lazy solution is to override the onBackPressed.

```
public void onBackPressed (){

        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) {
                webview.goBack();       
        } 
}
```

Comment: There is no Webview in child activity. This works only if I am in existing activity, that I know already..